# How can I turn a CONCATENATE formula into a hyperlink?

Tags: excel-formula

I can use the following formula to insert a URL into a row's empty S9 column that has a part number in the b9 column of the same row:

=CONCATENATE("https://www.website.com/search/?query=",b9,"&brand=all")

That turns it into a non-clickable URL, though; when the S9 cell is clicked on, the formula bar shows the formula and not a true link. Is it possible to next convert it to a clickable hyperlink?

Comment: `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.website.com/search/?query=",b9,"&brand=all"), 'link text')` should work

Comment: If I have to copy/paste in the link text by hand, I might as well do that in the field itself anyway. OK, I'll go back to doing it that way. Upvoted for good answer!

Comment: Well instead of `'link text'` you could just assign it the concatenate value

Comment: The concatenate value is in the post just before 'link text'  :)

Comment: `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.website.com/search/?query=",b9,"&brand=all"), CONCATENATE("https://www.website.com/search/?query=",b9,"&brand=all"))` should be all you need then to format them all as links

Comment: @Thomas__ When I used that formula pattern, it formed correctly in the worksheet row, but clicking the link did a search for "xxxxx" rather than the part number in b9. The b9 part isn't carrying over to the browser itself. Getting closer!

Comment: Strange, and value in b9 is it a reference to another cell or anything? As my basic worksheet carries over the value in a cell in the link

Comment: @Thomas B9 has the full value, a 4- or 5-digit number. I see the problem: the number was General and not a Number. Once I switched, it worked!